# Delete matching SSN based on array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, if-statement

I have a private sub that I call at the end of my code.  It's purpose is to delete any individuals whose SSN match a running array.  I have two sheets that it searches through and the second one works great, however the first doesn't seem to be working.

I attempted to debug it and it is finding the right numbers the one individual that I am concerned with matches the array, however the `If statement` doesn't seem to effect it.  Here is what I have, any and all help would be appreciated.  Again the issue is that the first `If statement` isn't working properly.  I have obviously changed the SSN's for security reasons.  Thanks again!

```
Private Sub Delete_Deceased()

    Dim tw As Workbook: Set tw = ThisWorkbook
    Dim visa As Worksheet: Set visa = tw.Worksheets("Visa")
    Dim nav As Worksheet: Set nav = tw.Worksheets("Navigator")
    Dim rwCnt_visa As Long: rwCnt_visa = visa.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rwCnt_nav As Long: rwCnt_nav = nav.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim Deceased() As Variant
    Deceased = Array(123456789, 234567890, 345678901, 456789012, 567890123, 678901234, _
        789012345, 890123456, 901234567)
    Dim visa_Inx As Long
    Dim nav_Inx As Long

    visa.Columns("P:P").NumberFormat = "@"  'Format the VISA SSN column as text

    For x = rwCnt_visa To 4 Step -1
        For visa_Inx = LBound(Deceased) To UBound(Deceased)
            If visa.Cells(x, 16).Value2 = Deceased(visa_Inx) Then
                Debug.Print "Row: " & x
                'visa.Rows(x).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
            End If
        Next visa_Inx
    Next x

    For y = rwCnt_nav To 2 Step -1
        For nav_Inx = LBound(Deceased) To UBound(Deceased)
            If nav.Cells(y, 5).Value2 = Deceased(nav_Inx) Then
                nav.Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
            End If
        Next nav_Inx
    Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: Presumably you should add an `Exit For` within the `If...End If` in both loops to stop iterating through the array once the row has been deleted. As far as your main question, is there anything different about the format of column P (what is the format prior to formatting as text)?

Comment: @BigBen - It's not even going into the `If...End If`.  I'll add it in for best practice nonetheless.  Prior to formatting it is simply General.  I changed to `Text` because the other `If` works great and that one is also a `Text` format.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. What does `Debug.Print visa.Cells(x, 16).Value2` return? Note - you could avoid looping by filtering and then deleting visible cells.

Comment: @BigBen - It returns the value that I'm concerned with and I also added in this `Debug.Print visa.Cells(x, 16).Value2 & " - " & Deceased(visa_Inx)` to compare it.  I'm looking at the debug screen right now and they are the same number, but the if statement is treating it as if it were false.  I also tried adding `Trim` and that didn't work

Comment: A bit of a stab in the dark, but what about `Left(visa.Cells(x, 16).Value2, 9)`?

Comment: @BigBen - `Trim` didn't work and `Len` returned 9, which is correct.  `Left` didn't work either.

Comment: Then perhaps `CLng` the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a question of the underlying data, perhaps try using `CLng` on the cell value.

```
 If CLng(visa.Cells(x, 16).Value2) = Deceased(visa_Inx) Then
```